# Can multiple multiplications in a SELECT be factorized to be performed only once for all rows?

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization

Let's say I have the following SQL query, involving floating point operations at the "AS ..." stage.

```
SELECT

T1.A * T2.B *  T1.D1 * T3.C AS A1
T1.A * T2.B *  T1.D2 * T3.C AS A2
(...)
T1.A * T2.B * T1.D100 * T3.C  AS A100

FROM TableName1 as T1
INNER JOIN TableName2 AS T2
LEFT JOIN  TableName3 AS T3
```

where TableName has 5.000.000 rows, and A, B C and D are rows from A, that are different from row to row. 2 Questions :

1 - will the **A * B * C** be actually performed **100 times** ? 
2 - is there a way to factorize the **A * B * C** operation for the 2 recurrent multiplications to be performed only once for the 100 columns of a row ?

Also, we could consider that the "B" would for example be a complex function call (SQRT(ARTCTAN(...(x))), thus the legitimity to want to perform it only once per **row**.

Comment: It is far harder to get rows from table than multiplying those numbers.

Comment: How many is "far" ? :) How about the "*" being a complicated function call (SQRT etc...)

Comment: assuming A,B,C or D is from tableA, yes, it needs to calculate over and over for every row.  Now if A*B*C = E is static, then why don't you just hardware value E instead (if your really looking to streamline things)

Comment: @Limey: Thanks : I just edited my flawed question. In fact, the values change at each row, I replaced the 10M occurences by 100.

Comment: So you will be SELECTing 5M rows each time? No WHERE clause whatsoever? (I'm asking because WHEREing on the A1-A100 columns won't be able to make use of any indexes!)

Comment: @CAFxX: definitely whering ! I'll update my question.

Comment: Is there a clustered index on an identity column?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume it would pre-calculate what it can (SQL Server), and then apply that to the column(s).

I'm pretty sure if you put the multiplied numbers in a single-row, cross joined select, that would do it. something like:

```
select D1 * res
from tableName
cross join (select A * B * C as res) as multiplied
```

**EDIT**

If the data is in columns, not scalar values, then maybe:

```
select t1.D1 * myAlias.res, t1.D2 * myAlias.res, t1.D3 * myAlias.res
from tableName t1
inner join 
    (
    select t2.keyCol, t2.A * t2.B * t2.C as res
    from tableName t2
    ) myAlias 
on t1.keyCol = myAlias.keyCol
```

Comment: I fail to see how this solves the problem.  A, B, and C are coming from a table; they are not constants.

Comment: My understanding according to the original post was that they weren't from the table. Hence my comment saying I would expect SQL Server to be smart enough to pre-calculate any scalar multiplication(s), and then apply that result to the data in the columns

Comment: If there was a clustered index on the ID field, you could join the table to itself fairly efficiently, with an alias, and then still use roughly the same above principle.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to create a calculated column on the table. In SQL Server, that would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName
 (
   A  float  not null
  ,B  float  not null
  ,C  float  not null
  ,AxBxC  AS  A * B * C
 )
```

The column would (ok, *should,* it depends on how the RDBMS has been implemented) be calculated once per row read and used each time thereafter. As a caluclated column, the formula is stored once for the table, so it would not measurabley increase storage space.

---

Update for updated question:

You are now performing a three-way table join (an outer join, no less) involving 5,000,000 rows. This will easily hit 10s, perhaps 100s, of megabytes of disk I/O (unless the data is cached from prior reads), and require merges, loops, hash joins, and whatnot to link up all the data. By the time all that’s done, the amount of CPU required to perform mere arithmatic will, in comparison, be trivial. CPUs are *good* at math.

To test this:

- Build and run the “full” query, as in your question
- Build and run a query that returns *just* the  A * B* C calculation.
- Take the “calc once” query, and use it as a subquery or temp table joined into the “base” query.

That last is the only way I can think of to force SQL to perform the calculation only once per row. However, that throws in an additional join (across 5 million rows), and from everything I’ve ever seen or read that’s where your performance will suffer the most.

(If you do this test, I’d be very intersted to see the results!)

Comment: Valuable answer. Now, what if the A, B and C of the select all come from distinct input tables (JOINED)

Comment: @SkippyFastol you'd probably have to use a (materialized) view for that